POCO 1.13.3 has 160 unresolved external symbols when statically linking to OpenSSL 3.4.0
I'm relatively new to C++, so I may be missing some key factors regarding the use of linking, especially on such a complex project.
I can build OpenSSL 3.4.0 fine, as we want a statically linked lib in POCO, which will in turn be statically linked into our binary. When building and linking it into POCO 1.13.3, however, we get 160 unresolved external symbols in the linking of POCO::Crypto, all of them being symbols that should be provided by OpenSSL. Compilation succeeds but it fails on linking.
This is using the base releases of POCO and OpenSSL from git and building on a stock Visual C++ 2022 installation with POCO's built-in vcxproj.
| Building C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
&"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj /nologo /m /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=release_shared /p:BuildProjectReferences=false /p:Platform=Win32 /p:useenv=True /v:minimal

  Cipher.cpp
  CipherFactory.cpp
  CipherImpl.cpp
  CipherKey.cpp
  CipherKeyImpl.cpp
  CryptoException.cpp
  CryptoStream.cpp
  CryptoTransform.cpp
  DigestEngine.cpp
  ECDSADigestEngine.cpp
  ECKey.cpp
  ECKeyImpl.cpp
  Envelope.cpp
  EVPCipherImpl.cpp
  EVPPKey.cpp
  KeyPair.cpp
  KeyPairImpl.cpp
  OpenSSLInitializer.cpp
  PKCS12Container.cpp
  RSACipherImpl.cpp
C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\src\EVPCipherImpl.cpp(172,55): warning C4244: 'argument': conv
ersion from 'std::streamsize' to 'size_t', possible loss of data [C:\project\externals\poco\Cry
pto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
  RSADigestEngine.cpp
  RSAKey.cpp
  RSAKeyImpl.cpp
  X509Certificate.cpp
  OpenSSL 3.4.0-dev
     Creating library ..\lib\PocoCrypto.lib and object ..\lib\PocoCrypto.exp
CipherFactory.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OSSL_PROVIDER_load referenced in function "public: __thi
scall Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory::CipherFactory(void)" (??0CipherFactory@Crypto@Poco@@QAE@XZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
OpenSSLInitializer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _OSSL_PROVIDER_load [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
RSACipherImpl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_type [C:\project\extern
als\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
RSADigestEngine.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_type [C:\project\exte
rnals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
RSAKey.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_type [C:\project\externals\poc
o\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
RSAKeyImpl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_type [C:\project\externals
\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
Envelope.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_type [C:\project\externals\p
oco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
EVPCipherImpl.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_type [C:\project\extern
als\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
EVPPKey.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_type [C:\project\externals\po
co\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
PKCS12Container.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _EVP_PKEY_type [C:\project\exte
rnals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]

...trimmed for length...

X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BN_bn2hex referenced in function "protected: void __th
iscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::init(void)" (?init@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@IAEXXZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_STRING_length referenced in function "public: voi
d __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::extractNames(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,cla
ss std::allocator<char> > &,class std::set<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::alloca
tor<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,
class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > &)cons
t " (?extractNames@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@QBEXAAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAV
?$set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$a
llocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@5@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_STRING_get0_data referenced in function "public:
void __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::extractNames(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,
class std::allocator<char> > &,class std::set<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::all
ocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >
 >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > &)c
onst " (?extractNames@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@QBEXAAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@
AAV?$set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V
?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@5@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASN1_INTEGER_to_BN referenced in function "protected:
void __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::init(void)" (?init@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@IAEXXZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _OBJ_nid2ln referenced in function "public: class std::
basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::
signatureAlgorithm(void)const " (?signatureAlgorithm@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@
D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_verify referenced in function "public: bool __thi
scall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::issuedBy(class Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate const &)const " (?issuedBy@X509Certif
icate@Crypto@Poco@@QBE_NABV123@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_digest referenced in function "public: class std:
:vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::fingerprint(class
 std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)const " (?fingerprint@X509Ce
rtificate@Crypto@Poco@@QBE?AV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@
D@2@@5@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_signature_nid referenced in function "public:
 class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509C
ertificate::signatureAlgorithm(void)const " (?signatureAlgorithm@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$
char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vc
xproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_serialNumber referenced in function "protecte
d: void __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::init(void)" (?init@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@IAEXXZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_issuer_name referenced in function "protected
: void __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::init(void)" (?init@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@IAEXXZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_subject_name referenced in function "protecte
d: void __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::init(void)" (?init@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@IAEXXZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get0_notBefore referenced in function "public: cl
ass Poco::DateTime __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::validFrom(void)const " (?validFrom@X509Certificate@Crypto@
Poco@@QBE?AVDateTime@3@XZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get0_notAfter referenced in function "public: cla
ss Poco::DateTime __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::expiresOn(void)const " (?expiresOn@X509Certificate@Crypto@P
oco@@QBE?AVDateTime@3@XZ) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_up_ref referenced in function "public: __thiscall
 Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::X509Certificate(struct x509_st *,bool)" (??0X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@QAE@PAUx509_st
@@_N@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_cmp referenced in function "public: bool __thisca
ll Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::equals(class Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate const &)const " (?equals@X509Certificate@C
rypto@Poco@@QBE_NABV123@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_NAME_print_ex referenced in function "class std::
basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Poco::Crypto::_X509_NAME_oneline_u
tf8(struct X509_name_st *)" (?_X509_NAME_oneline_utf8@Crypto@Poco@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$alloca
tor@D@2@@std@@PAUX509_name_st@@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID referenced in function "publ
ic: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X5
09Certificate::issuerName(enum Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::NID)const " (?issuerName@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@QBE
?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@W4NID@123@@Z) [C:\project\exter
nals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _X509_get_ext_d2i referenced in function "public: void
__thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::extractNames(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class
 std::allocator<char> > &,class std::set<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocato
r<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,cl
ass std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > &)const
" (?extractNames@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@QBEXAAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAV?$
set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$all
ocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@5@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PEM_read_bio_X509 referenced in function "protected: v
oid __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::load(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)" (?
load@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@IAEXAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _PEM_write_bio_X509 referenced in function "public: voi
d __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::save(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const
" (?save@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@QBEXAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
X509Certificate.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GENERAL_NAMES_free referenced in function "public: voi
d __thiscall Poco::Crypto::X509Certificate::extractNames(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,cla
ss std::allocator<char> > &,class std::set<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::alloca
tor<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,
class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > &)cons
t " (?extractNames@X509Certificate@Crypto@Poco@@QBEXAAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AAV
?$set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$a
llocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@5@@Z) [C:\project\externals\poco\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]
..\bin\PocoCrypto.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 160 unresolved externals [C:\project\externals\poc
o\Crypto\Crypto_vs170.vcxproj]


ERROR: powershell.exe ./buildwin.ps1 -vs 170 -action rebuild -linkmode all -config both -platform Win32 -tool msbuild -omit \"DNSSD,DNSSD/Avahi,DNSSD/Bonjour,NetSSL_Win,Data/MySQL,Data/PostgreSQL,JWT\" -openssl_base "C:\project/externals/openssl\build\x86\OpenSSL" failed!

This build system works on other machines but not this one, and it's not clear why. What is it missing to statically link these two libs for the project? My colleague has provided me with pre-linked libraries for POCO, but that's not permanently sustainable for me to be able to build the project from scratch.
EDIT: The detailed linker command:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"..\bin\PocoCrypto.dll" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:..\lib ws2_32.lib iphlpapi.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /PDB :"..\bin\PocoCrypto.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"..\lib\PocoCrypto.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH /DLL obj\Crypto\release_shared\DLLVersion.res


Edit your question with the full commandline used for linking. See this answer as to how. The linker may be picking up an openssl library from somewhere unexpected.

See this issue in the POCO issue tracker.

@Botje Adding commandline now. I used buildwin.ps1 -verbosity detailed this time.
